# How do I make Apache read symlinks to different partition?

Tags: apache, lamp

I have Linux Mint 13 with two ext4 partitions, one for / and one for /home. I just installed LAMP. It works fine except that Apache won't read symlinks that target the second partition. The server's document root is set to /var/www.

What I'm trying to do is create symlinks for each website in www to link to `/home/my-username/Documents/mywww/website_name` so I can access it via localhost/website_name.

I enabled `FollowSymLinks` and removed `SymLinksIfOwnerMatch`. I also gave 777 permission to the symlink itself and to the mywww folder and all its contents. But it just doesn't work.

The error log says "`Symbolic link not allowed or link target not accessible`". Setting the document root to `/home/my-username/Documents/mywww/website_name` also diesn't work and prints "`(13) Permission denied: Access to / denied`" to the error log.

I hope someone can help me out here.

EDIT: added some paragraphs

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a permission/ownership issue if you have  Options FollowSymLinks already set in httpd.conf.  What are your permissions for the Documents dir? Its usually 700 by default. Setting it to chmod 705 or chmod 755 may work.